# Java Scanner with InputStream not working

Tags: java, inputstream, java.util.scanner

I am reading an InputStream (fis) from a source and on which I have to do some multiple search. I am using Scanner class and I instantiate it after every search. But it works only first time. Is there a way to reset the Scanner object? I have no control over the stream.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                fis, MIFConstants.ENCODING_UTF_8)));
        int count = 0;
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            count++;
            sc.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.println(count);

        sc = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis,
                MIFConstants.ENCODING_UTF_8)));
        count = 0;
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            count++;
            sc.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.println(count);
```

The second print is returning zero. Any ideas about this?

Comment: Why do you need to evaluate and print the number of lines in the file twice?

Comment: I have to search for some line in the input stream again and again. So I have to do multiple scanning on the same stream. My first scanning works, but the next one doesn't cause it has already reached EOF. I thought if I create a new scanner object, it should start from the beginning of the stream. Any other way I can approach this?

Comment: You *can't* do multiple scanning on the same stream, as shown above. You would have to reopen it. But this is stunningly inefficient. You should scan for everything you need to scan for in a single pass of the file.

Comment: I can't close and reopen the stream as I am reading it from an external source. It's like a huge text file where I have to string search over and over again. I don't want to load in memory it will eat up the heap.

Comment: Did you actually read what I wrote? or just the first bit? not the second bit? where I said that would be 'stunningly inefficient'? or the third bit, where I gave you the solution?

Comment: Yeah I read that...but I don't have everything that I have to search in the first pass, I need to search again and again based on some user input. May be I can store the stream temporarily and then open-search-close.

Comment: In that case you should upload the file into a database where you can query it. Your present approach of scanning the entire file once for every item will not scale. It is doomed to failure.

Answer (score 0):

Create just one `Scanner`, and reuse it each time. The problem is happening because the `BufferedReader` `*buffers* your input -- which means that it reads more than it needs and stores it up for later. When you create your second scanner, all the input has already been grabbed by the first`BufferedReader`, leaving nothing left to scan.

Comment: That's the wrong solution and the wrong reason. It would happen even if he didn't have a `BufferedInputStream` at all. The reason is that he reads to EOS on the stream `fis`, so when he does it all again there is nothing left to read.

Comment: He's creating a second `BufferedReader` as well. That's not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> The second print is returning zero.

Because you've already read the stream to EOS counting lines the first time. So when you do it again there are zero lines left to count, so you get zero.

Working as designed.